# Did either Bohr or Heisenberg specifically state in writing, or speech, an interpretation of Schrodinger's Cat directly

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history, quantum-interpretations, schroedingers-cat

If we take the Copenhagen Interpretation to mean "what Bohr and/or Heisenberg think," then I would like to know if either one of them said, in so many words, "Yes. The cat is in fact both dead AND alive until we open the box. Then it becomes one or the other, only after we open the box, and NOT before."

I haven't been able to find this type of answer online or in books. It's frustrating. Just say it. I get the implications of the thought experiment. I get that Schrödinger put it out there to show how ridiculous the Copenhagen Interpretation of the quantum world is (perhaps, including direct personal jabs at Heisenberg). Likewise, I get that Schrödinger and Einstein prefer determinism and objective philosophy regardless of human observation; and, that Bohr, and Heisenberg, although not totally on the same page with each other about everything, did argue more subjective philosophies. But assuming Copenhagen Interpretation says the cat is both dead and alive is not enough. That's just assuming implicit assumptions about the interpretation, not explicit remarks on this specific thought experiment. What did the people say?

Probability and superposition are part of the math and science that come with the nature of quantum mechanics. But why is there still confusion about the thought experiment? Wouldn't Bohr or Heisenberg, both, or separately, agree that the cat is either dead OR alive before we look, we just don't yet know which it is, so we can calculate the probabilities of it being one or the other? Otherwise, did either of them or both, state ... "yep, it's not real until we look"? That doesn't seem like anything a scientist would say. But okay. Math is abstract, and everything is math really, but the philosophies spin out of control.

I don't think the Copenhagen Interpretation is any more bizarre than Many Worlds. These are all very smart people. But if anyone can tell me what specific people said about Schrödinger's cat would help.

Then there is Wigner's Friend and more, but for now, I'll feel better just concluding with the Cat.

Comment: Would this be better on [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat#Copenhagen_interpretation) has four to five references that, according to them, handle how Copenhagen reacted to Schrödingers cat.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the Wikipedia info on this several times. Those pages are usually pretty helpful and are footnoted nicely, but it's a pretty convoluted dance around the topic. If the Geiger counter detects a particle, the cat is dead, end of the story, but neither Bohr nor Heisenberg say exactly that. I get that we don't know if the nucleus will decay or not. That's random. Or that the Geiger counter will work. The Copenhagen Interpretation is not well-defined, and Many Worlds is science fiction. IDK. Does absurdity exist objectively? Or, is it just us that is absurd?